# Wordpress : Unable to upload image to Media Library from Android phone

Tags: android, wordpress, gallery, media

I have a responsive wordpress website, with a front-end Media Uploader. When I try to upload an image to the Library, I only see "Camera", "Camcorder" and "Documents". How can I select an image from my phone gallery ?

I've spend hours searching for a solution, but I cannot find anything.

Thanks in advance for your help !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click 'Documents' -> 'Hamburger Menu Icon' in Top Left -> scroll down until you see your photo gallery app (Photos for google, Gallery for Samsung, etc..) the you will see all your phone's photos.

Comment: Indeed this works. But if I didn't see it, i'm sure a lot people will miss it too. Is there no way to display the phone Gallery as main choice ?

Comment: Not that I've stumbled across.  Can you give an upvote to my answer if this worked and possibly mark it as the correct answer if you are satisfied?